# for, foreach отличия?

Tags: java, for

Почему-то не нашел нормальной информации в интернете и погуглил по темам на стаковерфлоу, но так и не нашел в чем отличие for и for each в Java? Понятно что for синтаксический сахар в Java и всё то, что обычный for может реализовать, можно реализовать и на for each(e), а что еще?

Comment: For использует внешний итератор (переменную, например), тогда как ForEach - внутренний итератор перебираемого объекта

Answer (score 1):

Если вы используете обычные массивы с циклом for-each, то на этапе компиляции он будет преобразован в обычный цикл for с целочисленной счетчиком-переменной. Но если вы используете for-each с коллекциями, то на этапе компиляции он будет преобразован в for с итератором (что-то вроде `for(Iterator it = myColl.iterator(); it.hasNext(); )`).

Answer (score 0):

Наоборот всё что реализовано на `foreach` можно реализовать на `for`. Дело в том, что для `foreach` у объекта должен быть реализован интерфейс `Iterable`, как вы например выведете чётные числа от 2 до 16?

```
for(int i = 2; i<=16; i+=2)
   System.out.println(i);
```

а вот через `foreach` надо попариться.

Данный фрагмент:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3");
for (String str : list) {
  System.out.println(str);
}
```

Эквивалентен записи через обычный `for` таким образом:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3");
for(int i = 0; i<list.size(); ++i){
  System.out.println(list.get(i));
}
```

Ответ @Bakuard не совсем корректен, компилятор переводит `foreach` в такой байткод:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3");
Iterator var4 = list.iterator();

while(var4.hasNext()) {
     String str = (String)var4.next();
     System.out.println(str);
}
```

Comment: Komdosh, а не могли бы вы кинуть ссылку, где можно почитать о том, во что компилятор превращает for-each для массивов. Или указать источник этой информации. Буду вам благодарен.

Comment: @Bakuard я скомпилил и открыл file.class, если вы компилите jar и у вас винда можете изменить расширение в zip и открыть архив, там найдите скомпилированный файл и откройте блокнотом

Comment: @Bakuard спецификация языка - [JLS §14.14.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2)

Answer (score 0):

Предпочитайте использование for-each циклу for.

Есть книга - Эффективное программирование Java , во 2 издании это 46 статья о преимуществах цикла for-each перед for с различными примерами.

https://vk.com/doc20299052_453037470?hash=65bcfc6f8cc717c341&dl=d313b5ec8243c42f0e

Цикл for-each обладает огромным преимуществом перед for , поскольку в программировании есть некоторые моменты, в которых он довольно таки уместен и прост в использовании, например:  вложенная итерация нескольких коллекций, простое выполнение итерации объектов, реализующих Iterable, также, некоторые вещи, написанные с помощью for-each проще понять благодаря визуальной простоты синтаксиса.

Однако, есть три условия , при которых цикл for-each будет бесполезен, это когда будет необходим явный итератор или индекс массива.

Если вам необходимо, могу вкинуть сюда пару примеров с различиями использования.

Comment: Давайте, я чет пробежался по книге, можете страницу написать пожалуйста

Comment: @MikeMclaren , 290 стр в книге , внизу слева на странице номер, там собственно все показано с довольно таки точными примерами, в браузере 311 (и в PDF формате)